# Accessing the attributes from a response XML with namespaces in node.js

Tags: node.js, xml, xpath, namespaces

I have an XML response from an API call and would like to know the best and hopefully simplest way to get the attribute values like serv:result and use:sessionTicket or any other leaf element in node.js  As I am new to these technologies not sure how to write the xpath for nested XML with namespaces.  The XML is given below.

```
<serv:message xmlns:serv="http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service" xmlns:com="http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/common" xmlns:use="http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service/user">
  <serv:header>
    <serv:response>
      <serv:result>SUCCESS</serv:result>
      <serv:gsbStatus>PRIMARY</serv:gsbStatus>
    </serv:response>
  </serv:header>
  <serv:body>
    <serv:bodyContent xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="use:authenticateUserResponse">
      <use:sessionTicket>AAABdFRR6SEAABUYA0gAKEgyU0sAAAAE9w==</use:sessionTicket>
      <use:createTime>1599142488352</use:createTime>
      <use:timeToLive>5400</use:timeToLive>
    </serv:bodyContent>
  </serv:body>
</serv:message>
```

I am using node v12.18.3 with express 4.16.1.  Have also npm installed modules xml2js@0.4.23, xml2json@0.12.0, xml-stream@0.4.5

I have done many samples but am unable to get to the child node attributes. I get undefined as I go done the xpath - I am attaching my code below  and the resultant output.

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');

var xml2js       = require('xml2js');
var parser       = new xml2js.Parser();

var app = express();

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    fs.readFile( './auth_xml.xml', "utf-8", function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log('error:' + err.message);
        }
        response.send('The File has been read');

        parser.parseString(data, function (err, result) {
            console.log('xmlns: = ' + result['serv:message']['$']['xmlns:serv']);
            console.log('serv:header = ' + result['serv:message']['serv:header']);
            console.log('serv:response = ' + result['serv:message']['serv:header']['serv:response']);


            });
    });
});
app.listen(3000);
```

The output to the console is

```
xmlns: = http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service
serv:header = [object Object]
serv:response = undefined
```

Any pointer as to how to get to the child node serv:result

Comment: *"Can you experts please guide me through this."* = "Can you please write the code for me." Not how this works. There is tons of examples of how to deal with XML (namespaces or no) in pretty much any language on the planet, including JS/node. Start somewhere that looks promising, try things out, and if you hit an issue with your code, you can post it here. Asking people to simply write the code for you is not the idea of this website.

Comment: Thanks Tomalak for your feedback - I have done many samples but am unable to get to the child nodes - I am attaching my code below  and the resultant output

Comment: I have updated my question to reflect my code and output

Comment: That's a lot better. Have you tried `console.log(result)` to see what it looks like? It's a regular JS object, you should be able to navigate that no problem.

Comment: tried console.log(result) and it gives me the following dump `{
  'serv:message': {
    '$': {
      'xmlns:serv': 'http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service',
      'xmlns:com': 'http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/common',
      'xmlns:use': 'http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service/user'
    },
    'serv:header': [ [Object] ],
    'serv:body': [ [Object] ]
  }
}`

Comment: That's what I get as well. This looks good, where is your issue? `result['serv:message']['serv:header']['serv:response']` should not give `undefined`, really.

Comment: ...oh, I see the problem. `result['serv:message']['serv:header']` is an *array*.

Answer (score -1):

Was able to solve it in a fairly simple manner using RegExp

```
var result = new RegExp("<serv:result>(.*?)</serv:result?>", "gmi");
var ticket = new RegExp("<use:sessionTicket>(.*?)</use:sessionTicket?>", "gmi");
```

Final Code - in case some other soul like me out there

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');

var xml2js       = require('xml2js');
var parser       = new xml2js.Parser();

var app = express();

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    fs.readFile( './auth_xml.xml', "utf-8", function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log('error:' + err.message);
        }
        response.send('The File has been read');

        parser.parseString(data, function (err, result) {

        var str = '"' + data + '"';
        var result = new RegExp("<serv:result>(.*?)</serv:result?>", "gmi");
        var ticket = new RegExp("<use:sessionTicket>(.*?)</use:sessionTicket?>", "gmi");
        r = result.exec(str);
        console.log(r[1]);
        t = ticket.exec(str);
        console.log(t[1])

        });
    });
});
app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Dont use regular expressions for XML.

Comment: Any reason why not to use RegExp? Any other approach to read the child node?

Comment: The reason why you don't use regex on XML has been discussed *to death*. XML is much too complex for regular expressions. The OP does not realize that all they need to is access an array to get to the value they want. That's a much better solution, and they are 99% in reach of it.